# Setting data in background thread and getting bad_access error

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiprogressview

My goal is to initialize a large amount of data on a different (non-main) thread, and then refresh a `UIProgressView` on the main thread corresponding to the large data load's progress. To do this, I use `performSelectorInBackground` to load the data, and update the progress throughout the way using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

I am currently getting a `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` error from one of the dictionaries that I am initializing, specifically the line where I am setting `self.someDictionary = @{...}`. `self.someDictionary` takes on `strong` and `nonatomic` properties, and is initialized on the non-main thread.

As a total newbie to multithreading, I am beginning to see that I shouldn't be setting a strong and `nonatomic` property (however, changing it to `atomic` still caused the crash). What else am I doing incorrectly to cause the `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` error, and how do I set a large amount of data to an NSDictionary on a non-main thread and still be able to update the progress on the main thread?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

Code:

```
//In viewWillAppear, from the main thread
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(populateDictionaries) withObject:nil];

//In populateDictionaries method
Dictionary *someDictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init];

//the methods inside the Dictionary class
- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        [self makeDictionaries];
    }

    return self;
}
- (void)makeDictionaries{

    self.insiderDictionary = @{ ...} //this line is causing the crash

}
```

Comment: Thanks @muku - I posted the code that shows when I first call the `performSelectorInBackground`, and eventually which method is causing the bad_access exception.

Comment: Make sure that ur code works in single thread

Comment: what is  `populateDictionaries` and can u try with NSMutableDictionary` with `nonatomic`

Comment: Hi @TonyThomas - the code works fine on a single thread, except that `UIProgressView` doesn't update accordingly.

Comment: @muku `populateDictionaries` calls the `alloc` and `init` of the class `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the process in background try Dispatch queue

ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Vivek, thank you for posting. If you have any specific code suggestions, or related SO questions that you could link, it'd be very helpful. While I am aware of GCD and the concept behind using queues, linking the entire document doesn't necessarily help me understand what's causing the error, or what could be done to solve it.

Comment: The solution to overreleased objects are the zombies. When this feature is enabled, a dummy object (a zombie) is kept on the place of every released object, thus allowing to debug objects which were released already. Very easy to enable:

- Double click your executable in the “Executables” in XCode Open “Arguments” tab
In “Variables to be set in the environment” (that’s the list at the bottom, be careful which one you edit) click the “+” button and for name of the variable enter “NSZombieEnabled” and for value “YES”